# Is it possible to include variables in TileSource.uriFormat?

Tags: c#, wpf, maps, bing-maps, bing

I have a MapTileLayer that I am specifying a TileSource for

```
TileSource mytileSource = new TileSource();
```

For this tilesource i need to specify a uri format. I want to include a variable inside this string because I have folders being dynamically created, and I want this UriFormat to point to the correct folders.

So how do I create a correct .uriFormat with parameters/variables?

```
mytileSource.UriFormat = ?????
```

Comment: You may create a derived TileSource and override the [GetUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.tilesource.geturi.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the UriFormat supports local folders. However it is possible to load tiles from local folders in the WPF control as outlined in this blog post: https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/08/24/local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-wpf/